# Force a transactional rollback without encountering an exception?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring

I have a method that does a bunch of things; amongst them doing a number of inserts and updates.

It's declared thusly:

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, isolation = Isolation.DEFAULT, readOnly = false)
public int saveAll() {
 //do stuff;
}
```

It works exactly as it is supposed to and I have no problems with it. There are situations however when I want to force the rollback in spite of there not being an exception... at the moment, I'm forcing an exception when I encounter the right conditions, but it's ugly and I don't like it.

Can I actively call the rollback somehow?

The exception calls it... I'm thinking maybe I can too.

Comment: check http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/transaction.html section 9.5.3

Answer (score 35, accepted):

In Spring Transactions, you use `TransactionStatus.setRollbackOnly()`.

The problem you have here is that you're using `@Transactional` to demarcate your transactions. This has the benefit of being non-invasive, but it also means that if you want to manually interact with the transaction context, you can't.

If you want tight control of your transaction status, you have to use programmatic transactions rather than declarative annotations. This means using Spring's TransactionTemplate, or use its PlatformTransactionManager directly. See section 9.6 of the Spring reference manual.

With `TransactionTemplate`, you provide a callback object which implements `TransactionCallback`, and the code in this callback has access to the `TransactionStatus` objects.

It's not as nice as `@Transactional`, but you get closer control of your tx status.

Comment: Would using `TransactionInterceptor.currentTransactionStatus().setRollbackOnly()` be a way of manually interacting with the transaction in the middle of a method that uses `@Transactional` ? Mainly for replacing the `setRollbackOnly` EJB methods. Would be interested if you have a comment on that. Thanks!

Answer (score 34):

This works for me:

```
TransactionInterceptor.currentTransactionStatus().setRollbackOnly();
```

Answer (score 19):

We don't use EJB, but simple Spring and we have chosen AOP approach.
We've implemented new annotation `@TransactionalWithRollback` and used AOP to wrap those annotated methods with "around" advice. To implement the advice we use mentioned `TransactionTemplate`. This means a little work at the beginning, but as a result we can just annotate a method with `@TransactionalWithRollback` like we use `@Transactional` in other cases. The main code looks clean and simple.

```
//
// Service class - looks nice
//
class MyServiceImpl implements MyService {
    @TransactionalWithRollback
    public int serviceMethod {
        // DO "read only" WORK
    }
}
```

---

```
//
// Annotation definition
//
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.METHOD})
public @interface TransactionalWithRollback {
}
```

---

```
//
// the around advice implementation
//
public class TransactionalWithRollbackInterceptor {
    private TransactionTemplate txTemplate;
    @Autowired private void setTransactionManager(PlatformTransactionManager txMan) {
        txTemplate = new TransactionTemplate(txMan);
    }

    public Object doInTransactionWithRollback(final ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {
        return txTemplate.execute(new TransactionCallback<Object>() {
            @Override public Object doInTransaction(TransactionStatus status) {
                status.setRollbackOnly();
                try {
                    return pjp.proceed();
                } catch(RuntimeException e) {
                    throw e;
                } catch (Throwable e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

---

```
//
// snippet from applicationContext.xml:
//
<bean id="txWithRollbackInterceptor" class="net.gmc.planner.aop.TransactionalWithRollbackInterceptor" />

<aop:config>
    <aop:aspect id="txWithRollbackAspect" ref="txWithRollbackInterceptor">
        <aop:pointcut 
            id="servicesWithTxWithRollbackAnnotation" 
            expression="execution( * org.projectx..*.*(..) ) and @annotation(org.projectx.aop.TransactionalWithRollback)"/>
        <aop:around method="doInTransactionWithRollback" pointcut-ref="servicesWithTxWithRollbackAnnotation"/>
    </aop:aspect>
</aop:config>
```

Comment: +1 for taking the time to answer a question that I asked 4 years ago and which already has a multiple upvoted accepted answer! :)

Comment: I like things to be complete :-)

Comment: For this case, you should probably use `@Transactional(readOnly=true)`

Answer (score 17):

Call `setRollbackOnly()` on the `SessionContext` if you're in an EJB.

You can inject `SessionContext` like so:

```
public MyClass {
    @Resource
    private SessionContext sessionContext;

    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, 
                   isolation = Isolation.DEFAULT, 
                   readOnly = false)
    public int saveAll(){
        //do stuff;
        if(oops == true) {
             sessionContext.setRollbackOnly();
             return;
        }
    }
```

`setRollbackOnly()` is a member of `EJBContext`.  `SessionContext` extends `EJBContext`:
http://java.sun.com/j2ee/1.4/docs/api/javax/ejb/SessionContext.html  Note it's only available in session EJBs.

`@Resource` is a standard Java EE annotation, so you should probably check your setup in Eclipse.  Here's an [example](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0415__EJB3/InjectSessionContext.htm) of how to inject the SessionContext using `@Resource`.

I suspect that this is probably not your solution, since it seems like you may not be working with EJBs -- explaining why Eclipse is not finding `@Resource`.

If that's the case, then you will need to interact with the transaction directly -- see transaction template.

Comment: Eclipse doesn't recognize @Resource as an annotation, and setRollbackOnly() is not a member of SessionContext (when it imports from org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SpringSessionContext). So... I'm closer, but not close enough :)

Answer (score 5):

You should have spring inject the transactional manager.  Then you can just call the rollback method on it.

Comment: that does seem like the right way to go... I'm investigating SavepointManager now.

Comment: this is causing an exception to be thrown at the end "Transaction rolled back because it has been marked as rollback-only"

Answer (score 2):

I have service methods annotated with `@Transactional`. When the validation fails, and I already have an entity attached to the current unit of work, I use `sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().evict(entity)` to make sure nothing is written to the database. That way I don't need to throw an exception.

Comment: This might be a compromise solution in a long session.

Answer (score 1):

> At the moment, I'm forcing an exception when I encounter the right
> conditions, but it's ugly and I don't like it.

Why is it ugly? I would argue otherwise. You have your `@Transactional` on your public method, with `rollbackFor` property like so:

```
@Transactional(rollbackFor = Exception.class)
public void myMethod() throws IllegalStateException {
```

and then if your method goes south, you throw a standard Java exception, probably:

```
throw new IllegalStateException("XXX");
```

This is beautiful, you use an existing standard Java exception using only a 1-liner, the framework does the rollback and that's it.

Answer (score -3):

Throw an exception and use the framework as designed otherwise do not use declarative transaction management and follow skaffman advise above. Keep it simple.