# How I do rollback with spring roo?

Tags: persistence, spring-roo, rollback, jta

I'm trying to find a method that allows me to do a rollback when one of the elements of a list fails for a reason within the business rules established (ie: when throw my customize exception)

Example, (the idea is not recording anything if one element in list fails)

```
public class ControlSaveElement {

 public void saveRecords(List<MyRecord> listRecords) {

  Boolean status = true;

  foreach(MyRecord element: listRecords) {
     // Here is business rules
     if(element.getStatus() == false) {
        // something
        status = false;
     }
     element.persist();
  }

  if(status == false) {
     // I need to do roll back from all elements persisted before
  }
 }

...
}
```

Any idea? I'm working with Roo 1.2.2..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about creating a new static method in the MyRecord entity:

```
@Transactional
public static void saveMyRecordsList(List<MyRecord> listRecords) {

  boolean persistAll = true;

  foreach(MyRecord element: listRecords) {
     if(element.getStatus() == false) {
        persistAll = false;
     }
  }

  if (persistAll) {
      foreach(MyRecord element: listRecords) {
         entityManager().persist(element);
      }
  }
 }
```

This may be more efficient than persisting elements and having to roll them back?

Comment: Thanks, but What if the process fails for any reason to persist in the last element of the list ...? I wish I could catch the error and I would like to do a rollback

Comment: I have updated the answer to make the save record static and part of the MyRecord entity class so that a client can save the list by something like this: `MyRecord.saveMyRecordsList(records);`

Comment: I have tried to do what you suggested me, but I get the following error: 
Not allowed to create transaction on shared EntityManager - use Spring
transactions or EJB CMT instead

Comment: I have updated the code to use @Transactional annotation.  If an exception is thrown during `entityManager().persist(element)` the whole transaction will be rolled back.  See the [javadocs](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Transactional.html) for the Transactional annotation to see how it works with exceptions.

Comment: Thanks Chris, I solved my problem largely thanks to your help... I have update your code with the solution...

Comment: Your reviews have been rejected by SO reviewers.  You could always add your own answer with you solution.

Answer (score 2):

What you're describing is a service method (saveRecords) that needs to be transactional.  Either annotated with the @Transactional annotation and then you raise an exception, or you will have to look into using the TransactionTemplate to get finer control in order to do a manual rollback.

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html

http://springinpractice.com/2008/03/18/annotation-based-transactions-in-spring/

[is there a way to force a transactional rollback without encountering an exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/832375/is-there-a-way-to-force-a-transactional-rollback-without-encountering-an-excepti)