# Java spring Junit Transaction won't rollback database

Tags: java, spring, junit, transactions, hsqldb

I want to rollback database after each test but it doesn't work, I've tried different types of Transaction management configs.
The `createNewItem method` object is still showing on other tests.

The goal of the rollback is to have the have exacly the same database objects and expected new ids on every test

ContextConfiguration:

```
 @Configuration
 @EnableJpaRepositories("se.system.repository")
 @EnableTransactionManagement
 public class ContextConfiguration{

@Bean(name = "hsqldb")
public DataSource InMemoryDataSource() {
    EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder builder = new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder();
    EmbeddedDatabase database = builder.setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.HSQL)
            .addScript("classpath:se/system/sql/create-db.sql")
            .addScript("classpath:se/system/sql/insert-data.sql").build();

    return database;
}

@Bean
public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory factory) {
    return new JpaTransactionManager(factory);
}


@Bean
public JpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter() {

    HibernateJpaVendorAdapter adapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    adapter.setDatabase(Database.HSQL);
    adapter.setShowSql(false);
    adapter.setGenerateDdl(false);
    return adapter;
}

@Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {

    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    factory.setDataSource(InMemoryDataSource());
    factory.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter());
    factory.setPackagesToScan("se.system.model");
    return factory;
}
```

Junit test with hsqldb:

```
 @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
 @ContextConfiguration(classes = {ContextConfiguration.class })
 @TestExecutionListeners
 @Transactional
 public class ServiceTest {

@Rule
public ExpectedException thrown = ExpectedException.none();

private static Service service;

private static AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context;

@BeforeClass
public static void setup() {
    context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
    context.register(ContextConfiguration.class);
    context.scan("se.system");
    context.refresh();
    Service = context.getBean(Service.class);
}


@Test
public void createNewItem() {

    System.out.println(((List<Item>) service.getAllitem()).size());
    Item item = Service
            .saveOrUpdateItem(new Item("Title", "Description"));
    System.out.println(Item);
    assertEquals(new Long(4L), Item.getId());
}
```

Comment: Hi, Where have you set autocommit to false?

Comment: Hey, I was looking for that too, but I didn't find where to turn it to false so I thought it already was false by default.

Comment: Can you post the service class code with the method saveOrUpdateItem?

Comment: Even if the test does roll back, i.e. un-inserts the Item object, the id generator won't roll back if it is generated by an identity column. So running the test twice on the same database will definitely fail in the second time if it succeeded the first time.

Comment: Ok but the database object is still there after the test if I print them all out

Comment: Could it be the way you initialize the service class? I make my class under test a non static field and use the @Autowired annotation.

Comment: I don't think so , it runs without Autowired on the service variables, I run Autowired on repository inside service though

Comment: Do you have the transaction demarcation on the service methods (@Transactional annotation) ? If so, then the rollback will not work. I usually test only the repositories with a test DB and use repository mocks for the service tests.

Comment: Answer of user skaffman might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/832375/is-there-a-way-to-force-a-transactional-rollback-without-encountering-an-excepti

Comment: You are loading another context not related... Remove the `setup` method  and `@TestExecutionListener` annotation. As Spring already creates the context that is what the `@ContextConfiguration` and `@RunWith` do. Remove `static` from the `Service` field and just put `@Autowired` on it.

Answer (score 0):

That’s how I usually annotate my test classes:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { JPAUnitTestConfiguration.class })
@Transactional //rollback if exception occurs during test method
@TransactionConfiguration(defaultRollback = true) //rollback at end of method
@DirtiesContext(classMode = ClassMode.AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
public class FooBarTest {
}
```

Add @TransactionConfiguration(defaultRollback = true) to your test class.

My transaction configuration:

```
import java.sql.SQLException;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.FilterType;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.EmbeddedDatabaseType;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

import ch.ams.pois.repository.AuthTokenRepository;
import ch.ams.pois.repository.GroupRepository;
import ch.ams.pois.repository.InvitationRepository;
import ch.ams.pois.repository.LocationRepository;
import ch.ams.pois.repository.UserRepository;


@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = JPAConfiguration.JPA_REPOSITORIES_BASE_PACKAGES, 
includeFilters = @ComponentScan.Filter(value = { 
        UserRepository.class, LocationRepository.class, 
        GroupRepository.class, AuthTokenRepository.class, 
        InvitationRepository.class }, 
        type = FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE))
public class JPAUnitTestConfiguration extends JPAConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() throws SQLException {
        EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder builder = new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder();
        return builder.setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.H2).build();
    }
}
```

The dependencies for the persistence layer:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.173</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>9.2-1003-jdbc4</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: It still doens't rollback still with that and the TransactionConfiguration is deprecated

Comment: Does that work for you currently and if so could you share how you have configured transaction management?

Comment: It works for me. Just tested it. But I use older libaries because the project is not being updated anymore.