# Should I use JPA EntityManager.clear() over EntityManager.detach()

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have an app running on Hibernate with JPA. And in my spring service classes (`@Service`), I put the `@Transactional` annotation.

I have some scenarios where the I need to halt or revert changes to a record. While JPA by default will auto-persist the changes at end of transaction, though I do not explicitly trigger the repository's `save()` command.

I prefer to use `EntityManager.detach(Object entity)` to revert / halt the changes. To my understanding, this detach method shall only revert the changes on the given entity / DTO object. However at times, this detach method seems doesn't work as expected, the changes are still persisted into DB.

I have then found some suggestion about using the EntityManager.clear()` method. I tested it, and it could revert / halt the changes.

However, my concern is, does this `EntityManager.clear()` method impact other entities as well. Let's say we have concurrent transactions happening, will `clear()` detach all those other entities unintentionally? If it really does impact other entities, what's the workaround I could have?

Please advise.

Comment: Why don't you simply rollback the transaction?

Answer (score 1):

[`EntityManager.clear()`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#clear--) will detach all entities within a persistence context, throwing away the changes made to them in the transaction so far.

[`detach`](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#detach-java.lang.Object-) should ignore all the changes that have not been flushed to the DB already. So either there is a flush happening somewhere or it may be a bug in the persistence provider implementation.

As Simon points out in the comment, doing a rollback seems like a more natural solution (and `clear` will do pretty much the same w.r.t. the pending changes).

Comment: Can you advise on how to rollback the transaction without throwing the runtime exception?

Comment: "EntityManager.clear() will detach all entities within a persistence context, throwing away the changes made to them in the transaction so far." ---- The word "within a persistence context" here does it means it should not impact other transaction chains, but only the current transaction chain? Meanings if there are multiple users doing different transactions concurrently, those other transactions just wont be affected?

Comment: 1. It is possible with [some effort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/832375/force-a-transactional-rollback-without-encountering-an-exception). Although throwing an exception and catching it at a higher level seems like a cleaner solution to me.
2. Yes, it will affect only the persistence context associated with the current transaction.

Comment: Noted with thanks